How to prevent “iTerm.app” would like to access data from other apps
5.10) on a MacBookPro M1 Max with MacOS 15.1.1.
After the Mac has started an Bash-Script automatically starts and should do the following:
function ragx() {
   cd ~/projects/chroma
   docker-compose down // This is just a workaround to clear old docker sessions
   docker-compose up -d --build
   docker logs -f chroma-server-1
}

This works up to the last line where I want it to print out the docker logs. EVERYTIME it hits this line a Dialog appears, saying '“iTerm.app” would like to access data from other apps.' and asks me to allow this.
Can I allow this somewhere in general?
In older MacOS versions this dialog has not appeared.

See the "Full Disk Access" answer in the linked question.
